# Is it possible for a function to not have a decreasing and increasing interval? If so, how do we show it mathematically?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Is it possible for a function to not have a maxima or a minima? (S.t. I can't find the decreasing and increasing interval.) If so, how do we show it mathematically?

I was practicing and found these two functions.

$a. f(x) = x+\sqrt{x^2-1} $ and $b. f(x) = \frac{x^2}{x^2+4} $

$a. f'(x) = 1 + \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-1}} = 0$
However, I can't find the extrema.
I tried to multiply with $\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$ and obtain
$x\sqrt{x^2-1}=-x^2+1$
But I still can't find the extrema.
If I only paid attention to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$, I'll obtain $x=-1$ or $x=1$.
Thus, $f(-1)=-1$ as the minimum value and $f(1)=1$ as the maximum value.
But I think this is wrong.

$b. f'(x) = \frac{2x(x^2+4)-x^2(2x)}{(x^2+4)^2}=0$
$x=0$ 
$---0+++$ 
So I know that $0$ will give us the minimum value. But what about the maxima?
$f''(x)=\frac{8(-3x^2+4)}{(x^2+4)^3}$ 
$f''(0)=\frac{1}{2} >0$ So 0 will really gives the minimum.
So, the function decreases when x<0 and increases when x>0.

Comment: $f(x)=x$ has no maxima nor minima

Comment: Or any strictly monotonic function on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @saulspatz but how to show it (since $f'(x)=1$ is a constant)?

Comment: So $f'(x)=0$ has no solution, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*a.* As you wrote, $f'(x)=1+\frac x{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$. It turns out that $f'(x)<0$ if $x<-1$ and that $f'(x)>0$ if $x>1$. So, $f$ is strictly decreasing on $(-\infty,-1]$ and strictly increasing on $[1,\infty)$. So, since $f(-1)=-1$ and since $f(1)=1$, the minimum of $f$ is $-1$ and it has no maximum.

$b.$ Note that$$f(x)=1-\frac4{x^2+4}.$$So, since $x^2+4$ is strictly increasing on $[0,\infty)$ and strictly decreasing on $(-\infty,0]$, $f$ is strictly decreasing on$[0,\infty)$ and strictly increasing on $(-\infty,0]$. Therefore, its minimum is $0(=f(0))$ and it has no maximum.

Answer (score 1):

For the first problem, $1 + \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-1}} = 0$ gives $$\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}=-1\\x=-\sqrt{x^2-1}\\x^2=x^2-1$$ which has no solution, so the derivative never vanishes.  That means that the function has no extremum at a point of differentiability, but we still have to consider other points.

The natural domain of the function is $|x|\geq1$ and the function fails to be differentiable at $x=\pm1$.  The function takes its absolute minimum value of $-1$ at $x=-1$, which you can show by proving that $f$ decreases when $x<-1$.  (Obviously, $f(x)>0$ for $x\geq1$.)